# How can I solve this TextField Underline issue?

Tags: flutter

I have face a issue in flutter textfield , When I am trying to use underline property in my code - show some field good some issued.

How can I solve this issue, help me someone

### Here is the issue :

[image]

### This is my reuseable code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../configs/appColors.dart';

class LoginSignUpFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginSignUpFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.icons,
    this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String? labelText;

  final IconData icons;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      autocorrect: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
        ),
        // enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: black45),
        // ),
        // focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: black45),
        // ),
        // border: UnderlineInputBorder(
        //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: black45),
        // ),
        hintText: labelText,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: black45,
          fontSize: 15,
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          icons,
          color: black45,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### This is SignUp screen Code :

```
import 'package:duaredoctor_app/src/configs/appColors.dart';
import 'package:duaredoctor_app/src/configs/appUtils.dart';
import 'package:duaredoctor_app/src/pages/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:duaredoctor_app/src/widgets/formField/loginSignUpForm.dart';
import 'package:duaredoctor_app/src/widgets/kText.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            FittedBox(
              child: Container(
                height: Get.height,
                width: Get.width,
                child: Stack(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 150,
                      width: Get.width,
                      color: green50,
                      child: KText(
                        text: 'REGISTER',
                        color: white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 130,
                      child: Container(
                        height: Get.height,
                        width: Get.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: paddingH10V10,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              sizeH40,
                              LoginSignUpFormField(
                                labelText: 'Full name',
                                icons: Icons.person_outlined,
                              ),
                              sizeH20,
                              LoginSignUpFormField(
                                labelText: 'Email',
                                icons: Icons.email_outlined,
                              ),
                              sizeH20,
                              LoginSignUpFormField(
                                labelText: 'Phone',
                                icons: Icons.call_outlined,
                              ),
                              sizeH20,
                              LoginSignUpFormField(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                icons: Icons.lock_outline,
                              ),
                              sizeH20,
                              LoginSignUpFormField(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                icons: Icons.lock_outline,
                              ),
                              sizeH30,
                              Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: Get.width,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  color: greenDark,
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: KText(
                                    text: 'Login',
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    color: white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              sizeH30,
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: [
                                  KText(
                                    text: 'Already have an account?',
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: black54,
                                  ),
                                  InkWell(
                                    onTap: () => Get.to(LoginPage()),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: paddingH10,
                                      child: KText(
                                        text: 'Login',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 174, 255),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Posting garbage to bypass the minimum text requirements is not acceptable. It's an insult to everyone here that you're asking to help you. If you can't respect the site guidelines, you should find somewhere else to ask for help.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example how to do it

```
TextField(
................
.....................
border:  InputBorder.none,

)
```

make all border to  InputBorder.none, that is (focusedErrorBorder,focusedBorder,enabledBorder,errorBorder,etc...)

Comment: same issue bro.

Comment: can you specify the issue , is that the input field bottom border

Comment: ok edited this answer , i think the above one is the issue